# Excel VBA, how do i add value to a number of cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to theoretically add run hours and increase the date for a number of machines every day by clicking a button. What I got is weak, looks like this and only adds value for one unit;

```
Sub Knapp10_Klicka()

Worksheets(1).Range("C2").Value = Worksheets(1).Range("C2").Value + 24
Worksheets(1).Range("E2").Value = Worksheets(1).Range("E2").Value + 1

End Sub
```

Where C column is run hours and E column is the date it was measured.

So if i click the button it adds 24 run hours and 1 day to one of the units, but i want it to add that for the entire C and E column for the cells that has value in them, in case I add another machine to the list. Is there a way to loop this command?

Comment: You would need to loop through each cell in a range of columns and then do the same check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range

    Set rng = Range("C:C").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
    For Each r In rng
        r.Value = r.Value + 24
    Next r

    Set rng = Range("E:E").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
    For Each r In rng
        r.Value = r.Value + 1
    Next r

End Sub
```

It automatically detects the limits of the operation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
Sub WalkThePlank()

Dim startRow As Integer
startRow = 1         ' ENSURE THIS BE THE FIRST ROW OF YE DATA

Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("C1:C500")    'ENTER THE RANGE WHERE YOUR TREASURE LIES

For Each cell In r

    If (Range("C" & startRow).Value <> "") Then
        Range("C" & startRow).Value = Range("C" & startRow).Value + 24 ' Gold cap'ain
    End If

    If (Range("E" & startRow).Value <> "") Then
        Range("E" & startRow).Value = Range("E" & startRow).Value + 1   ' aaahh, doubloons
    End If
    startRow = startRow + 1

Next

End Sub
```

Remember, there is no undo function, so I do suggest you take a back up of the file first!

Before VBa executes:

[image]

After VBa executes:

[image]

Comment: This one works aswell, but your is better as i need to define end cell with this; Sub Knapp1_Klicka()
Dim x As Long

For x = 2 To 35
    Cells(x, "B").Value = Cells(x, "B").Value + 24
    Cells(x, "C").Value = Cells(x, "C").Value + 1
  Next x

Comment: If it's right, feel free to upvote, mark as answer (green tick) or both @Jackthenotsogoodexcelman

Comment: Would be better to loop each row until the last row, rather than each cell in the range. If the range consisted of two columns (say, C1:D500), you'd end up looping through each row twice.